# multiple file rename based on modification date

Tags: command-line, batch-rename

I have looked on the web on multiple sites but I can't seem to find a solution and the man page is not clear (I'm a beginner with the CLI). This is my problem: I have about 200 files in a directory, these files do not have an extensions and are named incorrectly.

For simplicity, imagine all files to be something like:

```
Delta ---   2.0K ---  01/01/1993
Gamma ---   2.1k ---  01/01/1991
Alfa  ---   2.2k ---  04/15/1992
Bravo ---   2.3k ---  04/10/1992
```

What I am trying to do is:

rename all files in this way 1, 2, 3,.., but such that the name is set according to the whole date  (not just the year or the month), so the output should look something like

```
1 ---   2.1k ---  01/01/1991
2 ---   2.3k ---  04/10/1992
3 ---   2.2k ---  04/15/1992
4 ---   2.0k ---  01/01/1993
```

Also, I want to add an extension, eg .TXT so the final output can be:

```
1.txt ---   2.1k ---  01/01/1991
2.txt ---   2.3k ---  04/10/1992
3.txt ---   2.2k ---  04/15/1992
4.txt ---   2.0k ---  01/01/1993
```

Comment: I don't understand: your file extension is before the rest of the name? And the "---" does it represent an undefined section of the name or is it actually in the name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having done something like this before, I can assure you it's easy to make a typo that will give you an even larger problem that you already have.   Use this information at your own risk.

At bash prompt;

```
i=0 ; for f in `ls -rt` ; do i=$(expr $i + 1); mv $f $i.txt; done
```

- `i` acts as a counter
- `ls -rt` lists files in reverse order by **modification** time - if you've copied, moved or otherwise modified the files, this may not give you the file ordering you expect. Check it carefully by running `ls -rt` as a separate command and check it - twice.
- `for f in`ls -rt`; do` iterates of the list of files with 'f' taking on each file name
- `i=$(expr $i + 1)` increments the counter
- `mv $f $i.txt` renames the file using the counter, and adding the .txt extension
- `done` closes the loop
- note that commands in the loop are separated by semicolons, so if you add another command, follow it with a semicolon

Comment: it fails to rename the files which has spaces.

Comment: @simplemind if you want to simple easy. use shell arithmetic expression `$((...))` like `...;do mv "$f" "$((i+=1)).txt"; done` and also quote the file name `"$f"` and destination name `"$((i+=1)).txt"` if file has a space in its name.

Answer (score 0):

Through python,

`script.py`

```
import os
import shutil
directory = sys.argv[1]
count = '0'
for item in os.listdir(directory):
    count = str(int(count)+1)
    newname = re.sub(r'.*', count+'.txt', item)
    shutil.move(directory+"/"+item, directory+"/"+newname)
```

**How to run?**

```
python3 script.py /path/to/the/directory
```